# Verilog, comparison to not equal bit of variable

Tags: binary, comparison, verilog

I wonder if there is  a possible way to comparison below variables.

```
reg [7:0] var1;
reg [3:0] var2;
```

Here I want to check if `var2` is equal to last 4 bits of `var1`. Can I do that? 
 If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
if (var1[3:0] == var2)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the `reg` type is for 4-state variables (01xz).

Either of these is appropriate for synthesizable RTL:

```
if (var1[3:0] == var2[3:0])
if (var1[3:0] == var2)
```

In a testbench it is better to use "triple equals":

```
if (var1[3:0] === var2[3:0])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do `{if ~((var[3:0] ^ var2) | 4b'0000)}`

This should be easier for the compiler to synthesize.